# Cannot start build runner: Cannot find Gemfile in working directory

Tags: ruby, teamcity, rake-task, rakefile, albacore

I made a Rakefile to build my ASP.NET solution and run test cases. (My Rakefile requires Albacore and I am using Windows)
In **TeamCity** I created a build step with the runner type: Rake.

When running the build steps in Team City I get this error:

> Cannot find Gemfile in working directory : 'C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\78c29356760be3bf'. 
>   If Gemfile is located in other directory please specify Gemfile relative path using system property: system.teamcity.rake.runner.custom.gemfile

Here are my settings:

[image: Build Step Zoomed]

This is my Rakefile:

```
require 'albacore'

clr_version = "v4.0.30319"
framework = File.join(ENV['windir'].dup, 'Microsoft.NET', 'Framework64', clr_version)

@solution = "../../Codex.Repository.sln"
@bin_folder = "App.Repositor

y/bin"
@obj_folder = "App.Repository/obj"
@test_bin = "UnitTestsRepository/bin"
@test_obj = "UnitTestsRepository/obj"
@tests_dll = "UnitTests.Repository/bin/Release/Codex.Repository.UnitTests.dll"
@nuget_packages = "../../packages"
@msbuild = File.join(framework, "msbuild.exe")
@vstest = File.join(ENV['VS12COMNIDE'].dup, 'CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/vstest.console.exe')

task :default => [:clean, :restore, :build]
task :tests => [:unittest]

desc "Remove all binaries and NuGet packages"
task :clean do
  if(Dir.exists?(@nuget_packages))
    sh "rd \"#{@nuget_packages}\" /s /q"
  end
  if(Dir.exists?(@bin_folder))
    sh "rd \"#{@bin_folder}\" /s /q"
  end
  if(Dir.exists?(@obj_folder))
    sh "rd \"#{@obj_folder}\" /s /q"
  end
  if(Dir.exists?(@test_bin))
    sh "rd \"#{@test_bin}\" /s /q"
  end
  if(Dir.exists?(@test_obj))
    sh "rd \"#{@test_obj}\" /s /q"
  end
end

desc "Restoring NuGet packages"
task :restore do
  sh "nuget restore \"#{@solution}\""
end

desc "Building the solution"
task :build do
  sh "\"#{@msbuild}\" \"#{@solution}\" /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0;Configuration=Release"
end

desc "Running the unit tests"
task :unittest do
  sh "\"#{@vstest}\" \"#{@tests_dll}\""
end
```

How can I run this? And where can i add the Gemfiles?

Answer (score 0):

`Gemfile` is the standard resource used by `Bundler` in order to require the gem dependencies into the current folder and create a wrapper around them:

```
http://bundler.io/
```

You need to create a file named `Gemfile` in the project root folder. Define the source for the gems, And the bundler will install the dependencies from there.

In the step 3 you marked the bundler check. That's why your project is requiring it. If you don't need it, just uncheck it.

Comment: Where should I put this Gemfile ?

Comment: In the root folder of the project. The error stats it.